# Query Lookup Table and Convert to List

Tags: c#, linq, list, lookup

I am using ILookup from System.Linq to create a dictionary that can handle more than value for a key. What I want is to have a given Vector2 (as key) and then get all the values as a list or array that share that key.

I'm using the Unity Vector2

```
public struct Image
{
    public Vector2 pos19;
    public string url;
}
```

i first have a list

```
var items = new List<KeyValuePair<Vector2, Image>>();
```

which i fill using

```
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<Vector2, Image>(intpos, img));
```

and then I convert it to a Ilookup using

```
ILookup<Vector2, Image> Images = items.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

This seems to work but now later I want to find the values for certain keys
I tried using

```
var pins = Images.Where(kv => ((int)kv.Key.x == x && (int)kv.Key.y == y)).ToList();
```

but this doesn't seem to work
anyone have an idea how to get the values for a key as list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Key` of `Images` is a `Vector2`.  You need to obtain a `Vector2` to key into your lookup.

```
var pins = Images[new Vector2(x, y)].ToList(); // normally returned as enumerable
```